# Can i put an HTML button inside the allert window?

Tags: html

in a simple html page I have a button . Then I am calling the function with a allert command

```
<button onclick="sayYes()">YES :)</button>

    function sayYes() {
alert("ARE YOU SURE??");
                  }
```

i am trying to find a way to place a link button inside the pop-up allert window in google chrome ! :) 
can somewone help me?

Comment: You can't. The `alert` popup is a hard wired utility you cannot somehow alter. Take a look at modern replacements, all javascript UI libraries offer alternatives with much better optics and flexibility.

Comment: You can't do this with an alert. You'll need a modal. For example, like [this one in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a confirm box and redirect if "ok" is clicked.

```
<button onclick="sayYes()">Button</button>

<script>
    function sayYes() {
    var yes = confirm("Are you sure?")
    if (yes) {
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    }
}
</script>
```

But as wogsland and arkascha said, it is much better to use a modern approach.